# How to modify the parameters(cutoff,iteration) of the training model Opennlp

Tags: opennlp

I am using OpenNLP(1.7.2) Token Name finder for parsing the Unstructured data. Model is building on default parameters that is iteration 100 and cutoff 5.
When I try it like this cmd:

> > ./opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer  -cutoff 8 -lang en -encoding utf8 -data es_corpus_train_persons.txt -model es_ner_person.bin

then wrong:

> > Unrecognized parameters encountered: [-cutoff, 8],but

So my question is, how can I modify the parameters(cutoff,iteration).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
TrainingParameters tp = new TrainingParameters();
tp.put(TrainingParameters.CUTOFF_PARAM, "1");
tp.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, "100");
TokenNameFinderFactory tnff = new TokenNameFinderFactory();
model = NameFinderME.train(language, modelName, sampleStream, tp, tnff);
```

This should do it!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command line, you can create a property file like the ones here: https://github.com/apache/opennlp/tree/master/opennlp-tools/lang/ml

`.bin/opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -params PerceptronTrainerParams.txt -lang en -encoding utf8 -data es_corpus_train_persons.txt -model es_ner_person.bin`

Answer (score 0):

The default params are defined as:

`

```js
public static TrainingParameters defaultParams() {
    TrainingParameters mlParams = new TrainingParameters();
    mlParams.put(TrainingParameters.ALGORITHM_PARAM, "MAXENT");
    mlParams.put(TrainingParameters.TRAINER_TYPE_PARAM, EventTrainer.EVENT_VALUE);
    mlParams.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, 100);
    mlParams.put(TrainingParameters.CUTOFF_PARAM, 5); 

    return mlParams;
  }
```

You can tweak as you will by the method described by Nuwanda